# How to format a SP Online List Name ( Header ) using JSON via Format View?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json-formatting

I have used JSON to format most of the columns on a list and then some using "Format Current View" and "Format This Column" however I've scoured the web looking for a solution to formatting the List Title on a SharePoint Online List and can't find a definitive way to accomplish this. Is there a way to do this using JSON?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can use JSON to format the column in the list. But we cannot use JSON to format the list title.

We can add the custom code in the modern list and format the list title.

More references:

[Use an SPFx Application Customizer to add JavaScript (e.g. header) to every page in a site](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2017/06/SPFx-Application-Customizer-Global-JS-Page-Header.html)

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Comment: Please forgive me Amy. I missed you answer all this time. My sincere apologies and gracious thanks for your assistance.